# How do I Uninstall a Program and Dependencies from a tar.bz2?

Tags: uninstall, tar

I installed a program using `make` and `sudo make install`. Is there a command I can use to remove these files now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo make uninstall` is usually defined and removes most, if not all, files that were installed.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on the author of the makefile. Sometimes you can run sudo make uninstall from the same directory that you ran that command from, but it's rather rare honestly.

This is why it is usually best to install only from .deb packages, since they almost always can be cleanly removed from your system.

Comment: So someone could possibly make a package that is impossible to cleanly remove?

Comment: Yes, furthermore a package is really just a collection of scripts, so someone _could_ write a make install that replaces all of your files with pictures of cats. :) That's why it's important to trust your sources.